# Divide array in two parts in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, while-loop

I have an array of N elements. I'd like to divide in two arrays. The only condition is that the first new array is formed by the first three elements of the original array, and the second new array must contain ALL the other elements.
For example the original array contains `["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"]`. I'd like to create two new arrays:

```
first new array: ["a, "b", "c"];
second new array: ["d","e","f", "g","h"].
```

But my code divide a lot of time the original array. Why?

```js
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.strengthChartData = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "asd", "lol", "ahhhaha", "llllll", "ehhehehe", "oooo", "aaaaa", "bbbbbbbb"];

$scope.arrays = [];
var size = 3;

while ($scope.strengthChartData.length > 0)
    $scope.arrays.push($scope.strengthChartData.splice(0, size));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <h3>All elements:</h3>
    <br>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="array in arrays">{{array}}</li>
    </ul>
    
    <h3>First array:</h3>
    <br>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="array in arrays[0]">{{array}}</li>
    </ul>

    <h3>Second array:</h3>
    <br>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="array in arrays[1]">{{array}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Avoid while conditions where possible - unless you're OK with the possibility of something running indefinitely *in the background*. If something can be solved with a finite cycle, it's usually a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** for that

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"],
  arr1 = arr.splice(3);

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr) + '<br/>' + JSON.stringify(arr1));
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you don't want to update the original array then
 create  new array and apply **[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** or use **[`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)**

Using **[`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)** only

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"],
  arr1 = arr.slice(0, 3);
arr2 = arr1.slice(3);

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr) + '<br/>' +
  JSON.stringify(arr1) + '<br/>' +
  JSON.stringify(arr2));
```

---

Using **[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)** and **[`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)** without any parameter to copy all elements

```js
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"],
  arr1 = arr.slice();
arr2 = arr1.splice(3);

document.write(JSON.stringify(arr) + '<br/>' +
  JSON.stringify(arr1) + '<br/>' +
  JSON.stringify(arr2));
```

Comment: This will mutate the original. I thought (it wasn't 100% clear) he didn't want to mutate the original array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h"];

var b = a.slice(0,3); // => ["a","b","c"]
var c = a.slice(3);   // => ["d", "e", ... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slice, for example:

```js
var ar = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var p1 = ar.slice(0,4);
var p2 = ar.slice(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

As for why:

The length of `strengthChartData` is 12. In your while, you are pushing to your `arrays` variable 3 first elements of `strengthChartData` AND you are removing them from `strengthChartData`, as splice modifies the array.

So your length is now 3 minus. You are doing this while the lenght is greater than 0, which means it will run when length it 12,9,6,3 and will stop at 0. So you are actually pushing four times the first 3 elements from `strengthChartData` to your `array` variable